# What is the red cord around the chest of Shaolin fighters?

Tags: props, two-champions-of-death

[*Two Champions of Death* (1980)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0078428/?ref_=ttmi_tt) made me wonder why one of the Shaolin fighters has red cords tied all around his chest over his jacket. I've seen this before in other Kung fu movies and always wondered about it. Is it a Chinese medicine thing? Or good luck emblem?

[image: red cord on fighter's chest]

Comment: Maybe soem kind of [Obi](https://www.etsy.com/market/obi_cord)

Comment: You see them wearing it in films made by the same company, including [The Rebel Intruders](https://m.imdb.com/title/tt0081404/?ref_=m_tt_urv). I don't think it has any cultural significance. I think it's just 'flair' intended to make the character stand out and break up the lines of his white outfit.